# The type or namespace name 'ReportingServiceSoapClient' could not be found

Tags: c#, reporting-services, web-reference

I've about given up on this one.  I know this is a reporting services web reference however I know it's not either of these below urls.

> reportserv/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx
>   reportserv/reportserver/ReportService.asmx
>   reportserv/reportserver/ReportService2005.asmx?wsdl

Does anybody happen to know the URL for this reference?  Or does anybody know how to view all the web references on a server?

```
ReportingServiceSoapClient rs = new ReportingServiceSoapClient();
```

> The type or namespace name 'ReportingServiceSoapClient' could not be
>   found
>   I'm telling you ReportingServicesSoapClient and ReportInformation is not there.

[image]

[image]

I'm using this to view all folders inside of a reporting serices.

```
ReportingServiceSoapClient rs = new ReportingServiceSoapClient();
            rs.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

            CatalogItem[] HomeFolders = null;
            string reportPath = "/";
            rs.ListChildren(reportPath, true, out HomeFolders);

            foreach (var homeF in HomeFolders)
            {
                if (homeF.Type.ToString() == "Folder")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(homeF.Path + "=> " + homeF.Name + " => is this your home folder? (y/n)");
                    bool ynLoop = true;
                    while (ynLoop == true)
                    {
                        var readL = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (readL == "y")
                        {
                            ynLoop = false;
                            TargetHomeFolder = homeF.Path.ToString();
                        }
                        else if (readL == "n")
                        {
                            ynLoop = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("You must use y or n");
                        }
                    }
                    if (TargetHomeFolder != "")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: The first one you said is correct, http://myServer/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx. Are you sure the server you're using have SSRS installed correctly?

Comment: Here it seems like second reference is okay: http://a33ik.blogspot.com/2009/08/custom-workflow-action-which-renders.html

Comment: @FabioGouw Yes i'm sure see edit

Comment: +1 This question made me realize that there are 2 SSRS web services, ReportExecution2005.asmx and ReportService2005.asmx, each one with its own purpose :-) Until today, I've needed to use only the first one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReportingService2010 could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964295/reportingservice2010-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 1):

OMG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I want to get some more frustration out.  The difference is simply this.  You have to add `reportserv/reportserver/ReportService.asmx` as a **Service reference** not a web reference.  If you add it as a web reference you will not be able to access it.

Comment: I tried it here too. When I use add as service reference, Visual Studio creates a ReportingService2005SoapClient class. When I add as a web reference, it creates a ReportingService2005 class. "Service reference" adds a "SoapClient" at the end of the class name...